# Derivative of sawtooth with dirac deltas in result

Tags: dirac-delta

When I plot $$f(x) =\frac{\arctan(\tan(2\pi x))}{2\pi}$$ in *WolframAlpha*, it gives me an expected *sawtooth wave*.

When I try the derivative of this function, it gives me $1$. I expect that since there is a discontinuity in this function at $(2k+1)\pi/4$, derivative is not defined in those points in the traditional sense. But **I am looking for a derivative expression** that can include dirac-delta function. For example, when I try finding the derivative of $\text{Heaviside}(x)$, it gives me a result of $\delta(x)$. I understand that dirac-delta is not a function in strict sense. Can anyone point me towards a solution or generally how to approach this?

Comment: The Dirac Comb is the distribution you seek as a result.

Comment: @Dr.MV, I understand there will be a comb at the discontinuity points, but what is the scaling factor for each impulse in that train? Is it 1? How does it depend on the height of the discontinuity?

Comment: Good question(s).  The scaling factor is equal to the size of the jump in the discontinuity.  -Mark oh, P.S.  Don't forget the $1$ that adds to the comb.